# Having an error case label does not reduce to an integer constant using switch in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement, label, constants

I'm trying to learn C. I try also to code this program that is supposed to do :

The program chooses a random number between 0 and 100 and the user has to guess which integer was chosen.
Each time the user proposes an integer, the program should print :

'**High**' if the guessing number is higher than the chosen random number, and the user has the possibility to try again by entering again a new value

'**Low**' if the guessing number is lower than the chosen random number, and the user has the possibility to try again by entering again a new value

'**Exact**' if the guessing number is equal to the chosen random number

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int guess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x = rand() % 100;
    //printf("Random value is %d \n", x);
    printf("Guessing value: \n");

    scanf("%d", &guess);

    switch (guess)
    {
    case guess < x:
        printf("High \n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        break;
    case guess > x:
        printf("Low \n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        break;
    case guess == x:
        printf("Exact");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone see why do I get :

```
error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
```

Other try but the `srand` in the `if` doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int guess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x = rand() % 100;
    //printf("Random value %d \n", x);
    printf("Guessing value: \n");

    scanf("%d", &guess);

    if (guess < x)
    {
        printf("High \n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
    }
    else if (guess > x)
    {
        printf("Low \n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Exact");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whatever resource you're using to learn C should have told you that you can only have compile-time constants in case labels. What you want if an `if ... else if ...` chain. If your resource haven't taught you properly about case labels, then perhaps you should consider changing to something else.

Comment: Aside: "The program chooses a random number between 0 and 100" --> `rand() % 100` results in a value [0....99].

Comment: Zokulko, Must code use `switch`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, right it's `rand()%100+1`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Well, I use `switch`  for no particular reason ;)

Comment: @Zokulko `rand() % 100 + 1` results in a value [1...100].  I think you want `rand()%(100+1)` for "between 0 and 100".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Can someone see why do I get :" Well, let's try *reading* it. It says: "error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant". So. Where does it say `case` in the code? Could that be, for example, `case guess < x:`? What would the `case label` be here? Perhaps the `guess < x` part? Do you understand what an `integer constant` is? Is it possible to calculate `guess < x` ahead of time? So, is it a constant? If an error message says that something doesn't do something, then presumably that means, in a valid program, it has to do that thing?

Comment: So, let's consider the intent of the code. In your own words, where the code says `case guess < x:`, *what is that supposed to mean*? *Why is it supposed to work*? What is your understanding of how `switch` and `case` work in C, and *where did that understanding come from*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel good point. So  with `case` you couldn't use a condition inside! I mean writing this `case 3 :` means `if guess ==3` then execute the code inside my `case` right ? I've modified my question by adding another code that I've done with `if`, `else`

Comment: Now your new code should print the correct result. But what happens after the user enters a new value? What will the program do? What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, if the guessing number entered by the user is not equal to the random value, the program prints 'High' or 'Low'  (depending on the cases) **AND** the user enters again a new value until he finds the right number... But actually, it only prints 'Low','High' or 'Exact' without doing `scanf`, don't know why

Comment: I come back to the issue of what resource you're using to learn C... It haven't taught you about `switch` and `case` labels, and it doesn't seem to have taught you about ***loops***. If you need to do something again, possibly many times, the solution is a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.2 The switch statement)

> 3 **The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
> expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
> switch statement shall have the same value after conversion**. There
> may be at most one default label in a switch statement. (Any enclosed
> switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions
> with values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing
> switch statement.)

and (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 6 An integer constant expression117) shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
> casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof operator.

In this switch statement from the first program

```
switch (guess)
{
case guess < x:
    printf("High \n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    break;
case guess > x:
    printf("Low \n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    break;
case guess == x:
    printf("Exact");
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

case labels are not integer constant expressions. So the compiler issues an error.

Instead you could write using the switch statement the following way. Pay attention to that you need to use a loop. Otherwise the user will have only one attempt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int success = 0;
    srand( ( unsigned )time( NULL ) );
    int x = rand() % 100;

    do
    {
        int guess;
        printf("Guessing value: \n");

        scanf( "%d", &guess );
     
        success = ( x < guess ) - ( guess < x );

        switch ( success )
        {
        case 1:
            printf("High \n");
            break;
        case -1:
            printf("Low \n");
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("Exact");
            break;
        }
    } while ( success != 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

You could also to introduce named constant for values 0, -1, and 1 as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { Exact = 0, Low = -1, High = 1 };

    srand( ( unsigned )time( NULL ) );
    int x = rand() % 100;

    int success = Exact;

    do
    {
        int guess;
        printf( "Guessing value: \n" );

        scanf( "%d", &guess );
     
        success = ( x < guess ) - ( guess < x );

        switch ( success )
        {
        case High:
            printf("High \n");
            break;
        case Low:
            printf("Low \n");
            break;
        case Exact:
            printf("Exact");
            break;
        }
    } while ( success != Exact );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have you precised `unsigned` inside `srand`??

Comment: @Zokulko To remember what the type of the argument if the function srand. Some old compilers can issue a warning relative to the conversion from signed to unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

`switch ... case` does not work like this. You need to use `if` statements.

```
    if(guess < x)
    {
        printf("High \n");
    }
    else if(guess > x)
    {
        printf("Low \n");
    }
    else
        printf("Exact");
```

`case integer_constant_expression:` - also the `integer_constant_expression` has to have distinct value ie the value case to be unique in every `case` statement.

Comment: I tried to do that but no working, I'm not able to retry and ask the user to enter again a guessing number, I will  add my code with the `if`, `else` way